# EditText Label?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to have some layout a bit like this

```
[text tabel][edittext]
```

i cant find an attribute like html esque label. It seems to be the case that i need to use

```
[TextView][EditText]
```

but i cant get them to go on the same line this is my xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">"
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/boat_1"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/entry"
    android:hint="@string/IRC"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/boat_2"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/entry"
    android:hint="@string/IRC"
    android:minWidth="100dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/title_close" />
```

Comment: Try GridLayout. Maybe it's too complicated, but it maintain baseline, so that all the labels and edittexts are aligned. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have basically two options:

### Option 1: Use nested LinearLayouts:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/boat_1"/> 
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/entry" 
    android:hint="@string/IRC" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"/> 
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/boat_2"/> 
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/entry" 
    android:hint="@string/IRC" 
    android:minWidth="100dip" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"/> 
</LinearLayout>
<Button android:id="@+id/close" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:text="@string/title_close" />
```

Notice that I'm using `android:orientation="horizontal"` for those nested layouts.

### Option 2: you can use another content manager, like `RelativeLayout`.

The advantage of this, is that you can avoid nesting, thus your layout will be easier to read/maintain/inflate. This is a brief example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text_view_boat1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/boat_1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/> 
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/entry" 
        android:hint="@string/IRC" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_view_boat1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/> 
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text_view_boat2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/boat_2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_view_boat1"/> 
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/entry2" 
        android:hint="@string/IRC" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_view_boat2"
        android:layout_below="@id/entry"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Define `android:labelFor` on the labeling View to indicate which item the label describes.

Answer (score 13):

The design support library has the TextInputLayout which animates the hint text turning it into a label when the user starts typing and can also show a red error message.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

Answer (score 6):

**`TextInputLayout`** is the answer.
Just use the correct version from the android material library:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout

The `android:hint` param will display the label in the text area, and when you click on it label will be moved above the text field.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/points">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/points_gs_input"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your LinearLayout has the attribute `android:orientation="vertical"` so of course everything is going to be displayed vertically within it.

Try wrapping a TextView and EditText with a LinearLayout that has `android:orientation="horizontal"`