# android reading input from user

Tags: android, user-input

I want to get `input` from user . The inputs are `text` type such as name email phoneno :

Is `EditText` is the right way for reading input ?

Also i want to have the title of the input to be displayed like

`Name`
`Email`

And the data to be entered after these title.
So is it possible to have my `cursor` start from right end of the EditText and push characters to left as and when entered.

Also , now when i do `gettext` , even the title will be part of the read text .
IS there a way to get only the user input from `EditText`

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name" android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
            android:textSize="15sp"  android:textStyle="bold">
        </EditText>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: Is edittext is the right way for reading input?

A: Sure.  Why not?  There are other alternatives, but "EditText" is a good choice.

> Q: And the data to be entered after these title. SO is it possible to
>   have my cursor start from right end of the edittext and push
>   characters to left as and when entered?

It's customary to pair a TextView (also called a "label" on other, non-Android platforms) next to your EditText.  The label is read-only; the EditText field is changeable.  Wrap both in a Layout to make sure the "prompt" is adjacent to the "edit":

[EditText Label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741863/edittext-label)

Comment: Thank you very much. Regarding textview i need the label to be in the same view as the i/p .

Comment: is there a way to make start entering characters from right to left than the usual left to right

Answer (score 1):

for the title, you can use:
-textView above the editText 
-in the editText property in the xml, set the android:hint

Comment: Thank you very much. For my case text view is not useful as i want both label and i/p within same view. And i had tried hint but it comes as not :highlighted" . IS there an option to keep the hint text as highlighted. Also is there a way to make start entering characters from right to left than the usual left to right